# wrap multiple jquery addclass into one function

Tags: jquery, function, addclass

How do I wrap the below into one function (jQuery newbie)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.job:has(.active)').addClass('active');
   $('.employers:has(.active)').addClass('active');
   $('.about:has(.active)').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Doing the above, just uses the last one.

jquery.com seems to be down.

Comment: I'm amazed why multiple times same class 'active'

Comment: Chaining the methods won't make a difference if it doesn't work currently. Can you supply a sample of your HTML? Are you initializing the code when the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 2):

By using comma separated selector.like this:

```
$('.job:has(.active),.employers:has(.active),.about:has(.active)').addClass('active');
```

Comment: All the way to woking... nice and quick!

Answer (score 2):

[.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('.job, .employers, .about').has('.active').addClass('active');
```

[Multiple Selector in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Use comma seperator

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.job:has(.active), .employers:has(.active), .about:has(.active)').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.add()` function,

```
 $('.job:has(.active)').add($('.employers:has(.active)')).add($('.about:has(.active)')).addClass('active');
```

or you can use [`multiple selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a class to an element that already has it and that cannot be done. I mean it can, but it won't give you any effect unless you add another class.